# Powershell: Checking if today's backup exists

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have set up daily automated copies from various SQL db's on different servers (18 total) to a set of folders on a NAS, each containing daily .bak backups (Server A -> C:\Backups\A\, Server B -> C:\Backups\B\, etc.).  I need a powershell script that checks (daily) each folder to see if the copy was successful.  I'd like it to write to a log the name of the files that copied, along with their size, and the directory of the file that did not (i.e. the folder where the day's .bak should have been).  I have an array with the destination folders listed.  I have copied what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to check 'if object's lastwritetime = todaysdate' and log if it does/does not.  Sorry if this is confusing, this is my first week working with Powershell. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
foreach ($folder in $array.destination)
  {gci | sort-object lastwritetime -descending |select -first 1
If
   ($object lastwritetime.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date  #this is wrong, but generally what I want to do
        | Out-File "C:\Script\.log" | ft * -autosize)
Else
  (
  **WRITE DESTINATION OF TODAY'S MISSING .bak TO LOG***
  )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to format, and if you do, it must come before piping to Out-File. See if this helps get you started in the right direction:

```
$file=dir -path c:\scripts\ | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1

if ($file.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString() -eq (get-date).ToShortDatesTring()) {
 #file dates match
 $file | Out-File Log.txt -append
}
else {
 #dates do not match
 Write "destination missing backup log"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This script checks in the DB and flags if any backup failed. It checks Full, Diff and Log backups.

```
#Backup Check Version 1.0.
#List Server Name from 
$ServerList = Get-Content "D:\PSScripts\BackupScript\ServerList.txt" 
#Output file Location : Put is IIS if you want to publish 
$OutputFile = "c:\IIS\BackupReport.htm" 
 $HTMLHDR=""
 $BODYRED =""
 $BODYGRN=""
 $now=get-date
 $FOOTER=""

$HTMLHDR += '<style type="text/css"> 
    #Header{font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width:700;border-collapse:collapse;} 
    #Header td, #Header th {font-size:12px;border:1px solid #98bf21;padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;} 
    #Header th {font-size:10px;text-align:center;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:#A7C942;color:#fff;} 
    #Header tr.alt td {color:#000;background-color:#EAF2D3;} 
    </Style>' 

$HTMLHDR += "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Backup Page</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
        <p align=Center><font size=4 face=Bodoni MT color=#003333><B>Backup Report :Location</B></font></p>
        <p align=Center><font face=Bodoni MT color=Green size=3>Last Pulled : $now IST</font></P>
        <center><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=900 id=Header aling ='center'> 
        <TR> 
            <TH><B>Server Name</B></TH> 
            <TH><B>Database Name</B></TH> 
            <TH><B>RecoveryModel</B></TD> 
            <TH><B>Last Full Backup Date</B></TH> 
            <TH><B>Last Differential Backup Date</B></TH> 
            <TH><B>Last Log Backup Date</B></TH> 
        </TR>"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null 

## Function if you need to skip or include any specific DB
function CheckDBName ($DBName){
$NameFlage ="true"
    if($DBName -like "*DBName*")    {$NameFlage ="false"}   

    return $NameFlage 
}

##Get Backup details 
ForEach ($ServerName in $ServerList) 
{ 
    if($ServerName -ne ""){
    $DT = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LocalTime -ComputerName $servername
    $DateTime = (Get-Date -Day $DT.Day -Month $DT.Month -Year $DT.Year -Minute $DT.Minute -Hour $DT.Hour -Second $DT.Second)

    $SQLServer = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $ServerName  
    Foreach($Database in $SQLServer.Databases) 
        {
        $FLAGE="false"
        $color="Green"  
        $model=$($Database.RecoveryModel)
        $DBName=$Database.Name
        $FBKP=($DateTime-$Database.LastBackupDate).days
        $DBKP=($DateTime-$Database.LastDifferentialBackupDate).days
        $LBKP=($DateTime-$Database.LastLogBackupDate).hours
        $WDay=$DateTime.DayOfWeek
            if($(CheckDBName($Database.name)) -eq "true")   {
                            $tmp= "<tr><TD>$($Servername)</TD><TD>$($Database.Name)</TD><TD>$model</TD>"            
                if($FBKP -ge 7){
                        $color="RED"
                        $FLAGE="true"
                        }
                if($WDay -like "mon*"){
                        if($FBKP -ge 4){
                        $color="RED"
                        $FLAGE="true"
                        }}
                            $tmp+="<TD bgcolor='$color'>$($Database.LastBackupDate)</TD> "
                            $color="Green"
                if($DBKP -ge 1 -AND $FBKP -gt 1){

                    $color="RED"
                    $FLAGE="true"
                    }

                            $tmp +="<TD bgcolor='$color'>$($Database.LastDifferentialBackupDate)</TD>"
                            $color="Green"
                if($Model -like "*Full*"){
                if($LBKP -ge 2){
                    $color="RED"
                    $FLAGE="true"
                }   }
                            $tmp +="<TD bgcolor='$color'>$($Database.LastLogBackupDate)</TD> </TR>" 
                            $color="Green"

                    if($FLAGE -eq "TRUE"){$BODYRED +=$tmp}
                    else {$BODYGRN+=$tmp}
                }
        }
    }
    }
$FOOTER+= "</Table></BODY></HTML>" 
$FILE=$HTMLHDR+$BODYRED+$BODYGRN+$FOOTER
$FILE | Out-File $OutputFile

Exit

###########END#########################
```